# IIF IN postgreSQL where if no input then return all records

Tags: java, postgresql

So basically I am using a mapper class in java which is connecting to a PostgreSQL database;

```
"Where ABC = #{Parameter}"
```

This is what I am using right now to return selective records, how to get all records if no parameter is passed?

Comment: WHERE ABC= CASE WHEN #{Parameter} IS NULL THEN ABC ELSE  #{Parameter} END

Can this be used in any sense ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common pattern.  So long as your `where` criterion is passed as written and `ABC` is a column name, this should work:

```
  where ABC = coalesce(#{parameter}, ABC)
```

That will not return rows where `ABC` is `null`.  For that you need to have:

```
  where (   (ABC = coalesce(#{parameter}, ABC)
         or (ABC is null and #{parameter} is null))
```